# Construct sliding images using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a small slider with the social media icons, the div will contain 4 social media icons and on both ends arrow that permits to slide the icons.
Let's say we have seven icons like on next example, 4 are visible with the arrows and 3 of them are hidden.

```
    <div class="slider" style="width: 228px;">    
    <img src="http://goo.gl/UvyXCP" />
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://goo.gl/cfUTR2" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://goo.gl/oRd14R" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://goo.gl/8vusDB" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://goo.gl/3Tgn6o" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://goo.gl/C81toB" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://goo.gl/BPSKS8" /></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="http://goo.gl/fV0g9d" />
    </div>
```

I need the images sliding automatically, and if needed to use the arrows to switch from one to another.
I've tried a example, here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AxHqb/3/), but seems is not working. I think there is a easier way to make it.

I will be glad if someone can help me out here!
Big Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a sliding plugin for jQuery, you might like it :)

http://www.rosefalk.dk/library/base/index.html

In regards to sliding automagically you can simply add a timer event. The nice part about my plugin is that you can completely code your own frame for it. It doesn't magically create any redundant boxes (urgh!) :)

Fiddle: [FiddleURL](http://jsfiddle.net/dDyYw/2/)

```
$("#test").rSlide({})

var go = "right";
setInterval(function(){
    if($("#test").data("slideData").counter == $("#test").data("slideData").childrenLength-1)
    {
       go = "left";
    }
    if($("#test").data("slideData").counter == 0)
    {
        go = "right";
    }
    $("#test").rSlide({direction:go});
},1000);
```

If you want you can replace $("#test").rSlide({}) with $("#test").rSlide({trim:true}) it will trim the box to the correct size although it may or may not give the result you're looking for.

Also if you use the plugin i advise you to use www.greensock.com animation plugin, it gives a much smoother tween than if you use jQuery's built in animate capabilities (my script autodetects if you have greensock added, it's not a prerequisite).

Adding  $("#test").rSlide({direction:"right"}); to any element, like a button, will make the slider slide right. Remember to stop the automatic sliding first :)

Edit: removed overview for now

Comment: To anyone reaching this page be aware that the fiddle wont work unless you link the newest version of the base plugin. this is not an error, it is simply me trying to tidy up my server by removing old files. The script works, the linked library version has been removed :)